# Is it possible to remove nouveau driver from a dual graphics system? Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I've tried numerous times to get my nvidia card running on Ubuntu with no success so far, but that's ok, I don't actually need the power nor the advanced graphics that the card provides so I'll make my peace with it and let that go.

The machine in question is a Lenovo T440s with dual graphics card, here's the "lspci -nnk" output related to the video adapters:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation
>   Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
>     Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:220d]    Kernel driver in use: i915
>
> 04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M
>   [GeForce GT 730M] [10de:1290] (rev a1)    Subsystem: Lenovo Device
>   [17aa:220d]   Kernel driver in use: nouveau

The problem I'm facing now is that I've just made a fresh Kubuntu 14.04 install on this machine and almost everything works fine, everything but having multiple monitors.

When I connect a new monitor (either using vga or displayport) everything works fine and its even able to play sound through the displayport cable, the problem comes when I tried to disable the second monitor using the system setting interface in KDE or the special key in the laptop (F7), when it switches to only one monitor unequivocally my KDE session crash and restarts itself leaving me only the choice to unplug the monitor physically.

The only message I can get when that happens is:

> nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:04:00.0] GPC0: 0x4188ac 0x00000001
>   (0x1e70822e)

I understand nouveau is the open source driver for the nvidia card but I was wondering if it is possible to eliminate the nouveau drivers from my system since I don't really need to use the nvidia adapter and if that's possible how can I do it safely. And in a related question, do you guys think that that could help me with my issue?

Worth mention that I've tried Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity), Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and even Fedora Gnome 20 (all of them fresh installations) on this very same PC and neither one showed the problem I'm portraying in here.

Thank you very much for your attention, have a good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

"Driver Manager" in System Settings should have what you are looking for. It looks like version 331 is the most stable version for your device. Or use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings
```

You will need to reboot for changes to take effect.

The subsequent output of `lspci-nnk` should now report "nvidia" instead of "nouveau".

As for your issue, this may fix the issue you have described as the Nvidia drivers (from my experience) usually reduce system crashes.

Also,

```
apt-cache search nvidia
```

Will give you a complete list of Nvidia related packages and alternatives. I do not know how well the rest of the packages work.

Comment: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-14.04 "All New Driver Manager"

Comment: http://www.geforce.com/drivers "Manual Driver Search"

Comment: Hi @mchid, thank you very much for your attention, but I think there's a little misunderstanding, my question is that if its possible not to use the nvidia card or its drivers at all (open or proprietary) and for what I get from your answer that will only led me to use the proprietary drivers instead. Again thak you for your help, and if you think on another option I will happy to hear it. Best regards!

Comment: check this post out from webupd8 it may be what you're looking for http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html

Comment: and this answer down at the bottom of the page "I just install the NVIDIA GTX880M from my ASUS ROG G750JZ via this url (french site) Ubuntu FR forum" http://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04

Comment: Hello again @mchid it is not entirely what I was looking for, but I've tried the last two suggestions and they worked at least now I have a way to switch between the two adapters. I'll run a couple more tests but so far so good! Thanks for your help!