# Is it a good idea to install propriatery drivers?

Tags: drivers

A few hours ago I installed 14.04 ubuntu and configured it for 2 hours and it just crashed and ran in low graphics mode. I was unable to fix this by (got very tired of it) and I just reinstalled it. Now I am afraid of the same mistake - should you, or should you not install propriatery nvidia drivers?

Comment: It depends what card you are using - e.g. with Radeon card drivers you get those that [are supported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Fully_Supported), and those that probably aren't *(with the latter I would of linked [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Unsupported_Chips), but it appears to have a placeholder and doesn't say which cards aren't supported.)*.

Comment: I've had a lot of trouble with the proprietary drivers in an HP Laptop system, and reverted to the open source drivers.  You can also try the xorg_edgers which can be more advanced that the standard drivers, or the drivers in the oibaf repository which are not as egdy as the xorg_edgers but still provide an improvement in performance for me.  https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers

Comment: I have nvidia 325m graphics card. My laptop also has Intel HD graphics.

Comment: Since all of those drivers are free and "good" might be different for each user I would suggest to just try them both and make your own choice. I use the prop driver since I game a lot; " in low graphics mode" Ha. Been there and did the same. The error is due to either a non-existing xorg.conf or faults in that file. I nowadays make a backup of that file (of course the error never appeared again...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest going with the proprietary nvidia driver. From my experience, that seems to solve system crashes. Also, you have to reboot the system after installing the new drivers for the changes to take effect.

However, if the system crashed **after** you had installed proprietary drivers **AND rebooted for the changes to take effect**, I would stick with opensource.

Comment: @Fractal also, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04

Comment: @Fractal and http://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04