# Ubuntu 14.04 does not give resolution option that Vista gives

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, display, resolution

I have a dual boot machine with Windows Vista Home and Ubuntu 14.04 just recently installed. It has a GeForce 6100 nForce 405 internal graphics processor.  In Vista I can set my monitor to 1280x720 but in Ubuntu 1024x768 is the highest that will work.  I use an Olevia OLEVIA 23" 720p LCD HDTV LT23HVX for my monitor.  I know it says that the 1024x768 is the highest it can do on VGA but like said Vista will do 1280x720, I think even 1280x1024?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install drivers

Comment: Yes, I have installed and updated the Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Please open this file

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Find the section "device" and add this line to it

```
Option"ModeValidation" "NoMaxPClkCheck"
```

Now reboot and see if your resolutions are back

Comment: Thanks for the answer but all that did was give me dispay errors on restart.  I had to restart in recovery mode and it found the errors and sent a report.  Any other ideas are welcome, but I'm starting to think I won't be able to change this.

Comment: OK remove that line for `xorg.conf`, can you find if you have an Optimus GPU ( I think you do), If so then `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` (* is not a typo) and try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04