# Unable to install nvidia drivers on ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo z570

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, proprietary

I have NVIDIA GeForce GT520M graphics card on my laptop. Unfortunately I am unable to use it on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. I tried installing drivers from Settings>Additional Drivers.

But I am unable to succeed in that. After selecting the Proprietary driver from the list, as I click on "Apply changes", the progress bar moves a little bit and gets stuck there. I patiently waited for an hour, but nothing happened there after. Kindly help; I am unexperienced with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You have a optimus GPU please uninstall the Nvidia driver and install Bumblebee and follow the instructions

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-current
```

To install bumblebee in Ubuntu 14.04, run these commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-331
```

Now you have to install Bumblebee GUI to manage apps to be opened using nVidia. Here is the instructions:

Install Python App Indicator:

```
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

Install Git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Make a directory for git:

```
mkdir git && cd git
```

Check out the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui.git
cd bumblebee-ui
sudo ./INSTALL
```

Go to Startup Applications and add bumblebee-indicator

Now reboot.

[I did not write this the source is here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04)

Comment: What does this have to do with the commands I gave you ?

Answer (score 0):

Install nvidia drivers using command line, enter commands one by one.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

This will also install Nvidia X Server settings, using it you will be able to choose what GPU to use.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I have installed this. Could you please tell me how do I use my graphics card for the blender software. I have a mechanical switch on my laptop for enabling graphics card. But it doesn't respond when I press the switch.