# Ubuntu 14.04 unresponsive after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia

I followed the [second answer of this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517123/unable-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-14-04-on-my-lenovo-z570) to install nvidia drivers on my lenovo z570. But now, as a result, My ubuntu 14.04 is unresponsive. Mouse clicks not working. The login screen looks perfect, but after typing in the password, the screen's resolution changes to very low and nothing works...

Will i have to reinstall Ubuntu again ? or if any, what is the procedure to revert back the changes (uninstall all nvidia drivers).

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: What is your GPU

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce GT520M

Comment: Did you reboot ? If so you can remove the driver like this- sudo apt-get remove --purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-331

Comment: I got into this problem only after rebooting. How can i access the terminal??? Nothing works after i boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Please boot to recovery https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Answer (score 0):

First boot recovery mode https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Then remove the current driver

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-331
```

Now you can boot to your full install again, open a terminal,

Then try installing again but with two commands

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus
```

Reboot to confirm this is not the issue

Then run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Reboot

To switch between the two different GPUs first make sure this is installed and your system is upto date

```
sodo apt-get install linux-headers-generic && apt-get upgrade
```

Now install this

```
sudo apt-get install bbswitch-dkms
```

This should allow you to use the switch on your laptop to switch GPUs

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have got my Ubuntu running now. BUT I am still unable to use my GPU. Nothing happens(GPU LED does not glow) when I press the GPU switch on my laptop. I would like to see the option 'GPU' in BLENDER. Please help.

Comment: Please tell me, do you have two GPU in your laptop ? (Is this what the "GPU switch is for) If so please tell me what is the second GPU (likely Intel HD something)

Comment: Updated the anser for you

Comment: yes, I have two GPUs in my laptop. They are : NVIDIA GeForce GT520M &  Integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000.