# Problems difference with installing drivers for nVIDEA GTS 450

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

Help me I'm a newbie at Ubuntu or Linux.

I have a NVIDIA Corporation:GF 106 [Geforce GTS 450]

I thought I could just change my driver on the "Additional Drivers: menu for my video card but when I click the other options then "Apply Changes" it goes back to the Nouveau display driver.

(Can't post picture)
Picture link : http://s21.postimg.org/tjn690m93/nvidia.png

I have learned that I can install it using Bumblebee? or from nvidia directly? I have read a bit of things about it but still don't understand any of it.

What's the difference about it and what should I use?

And how do I install the correct drivers for my video card?

If it would be any help this is my specs

Specs picture: http://s21.postimg.org/ssug38jvr/image.png

Answer (score 0):

You can install drivers by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-prime
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to ASK UBUNTU Question [How to set up nVidia Optimus/Bumblebee in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04/625090#625090) That will most likely solve your issue. Follow the Guide and I am sure you will be able to setup Bumblebee correctly.

If you want to understand what bumblebee is and how does it work. Look at my blog for extra information.

http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.in/2015/03/p-margin-bottom-0.html

This is for additional information and understanding. However the askubuntu Link referred above will solve your problem !!

Comment: Thank you for the answers I got it to work. Also the screen tearing was solve by this.