# Desktop froze, rebooted, now login loop

Tags: xorg, login, lightdm

First firefox froze, so I started System processes and ended firefox. Then it happened again but when I ended firefox in System processes the whole desktop froze. So I pressed the restart button on the tower and now every time I enter my password the screen flashes black and then goes back to login screen.

So I pressed alt+ctrl+f1 and entered a shell. I then ran

```
cat ~/.xsession-errors
```

Here is the output:

```
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: gpg-agent post-stop process (3434) killed by TERM signal
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (3485) terminated with status 1
init: unity-settings-daemon main process (3468) killed by TERM signal
init: logrotate main process (3362) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_gedit.1000.crash) main process (3402) killed by TERM signal
init: upstart-dbus-session-bridge main process (3448) terminaed with status 1
init: xsession-init main process (3459) killed by TERM signal
init: hud main process (3480) killed by TERM signal
init: unity-panel-service main process (3492) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-BUS bus
```

Please, anyone, if possible, either tell me where I might find a file containing information about what's going on, or, if you think you know a solution, post a solution. Thanks!

I ran less Xorg.0.log and found the following warnings (WW) and errors (EE):

```
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cryillic" does not exist.
         Entry deleted from font path. 
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
         Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist. 
         Entry deleted from font path. 
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
         Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist. 
         Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.

(EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the system's kernel log for additions error messages and consult the NVIDIA README for details.
(EE) No devices detected.
(WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not permitted.
(WW) xf86OpenConsole: setsiid failed: Operation not permitted.
(EE) [drm] KMS not enabled.
(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory.
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting.
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section. 
(EE) FBDE(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found).
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with your graphics setup. Check /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Answer (score 1):

The first line suggests that OpenGL is not supported on your computer:

```
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

You can find a log with more information on the display configuration, and any errors at:

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

It might be worth copying the log to a memory stick, since it will be rather long:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log > /media/username/nameOfUsbDevice/Xorg.0.log
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I checked the log and added the warnings and errors into the body of my question above. Would you please read it and see if you recognize any of the errors? I still don't know a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have installed the proprietary NVIDIA driver. Unfortunately, it is failing to detect a compatible graphics card, so it quits, and leaves your system without any kind of OpenGL acceleration.

```
(EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module.
(EE) No devices detected.
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension
```

Can you check what graphics cards are listed by the kernel?

```
sudo apt-get install lswh
sudo lshw -class display
```

If you see an Intel graphics card listed, you may be able to get OpenGL support by [uninstalling the NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) and restarting the computer:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

If you have more than one graphics card listed, check if your computer, or graphics card supports the [NVIDIA Optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus) technology. If so, uninstall the NVIDIA drivers, reboot your computer, and make sure everything is working. Then you can consider installing the [Bumblebee software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04).