# How to install nvidia-smi?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

How can I install nvidia-smi? I installed CUDA and nvidia-352 driver but unfortunately nvidia-smi is not installed.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-smi
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-smi
```

Comment: How did you install the driver ? PPA ? nvidia website ? or did you build it ?

Comment: @markkirby, I installed it like what nvidia site said. 
    'sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_amd64.deb'
    'sudo apt-get update'
    'sudo apt-get install cuda'

Comment: Did you not also install the driver ? You must install both CUDA and the driver as nvidia-smi is packaged with the driver.

Comment: @markkirby no, I completely installed nvidia-352, Even I installed nvidia-340 but there is no nvidia-smi. My laptop has Intel 3000 and Nvidia 525M, is it important?

Comment: Yes you have a hybrid GPU right ? Intel and Nvidia ? First remove everything you installed with `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` Then see here for the driver instructions http://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04, then reinstall cuda, please see here for bumblebee docs, http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html

Answer (score 7):

*nvidia-smi* binary symlink created when you install the nvidia driver, as nvidia-340 in my case. Take a look:

```
darlene ➜   ls -la `which nvidia-smi` 

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Mai 24 20:52 /usr/bin/nvidia-smi -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_smi

darlene ➜   ls -la /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_smi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Mai 24 20:52 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_smi -> /usr/lib/nvidia-340/bin/nvidia-smi
```

And the final binary comes from:

```
darlene ➜  dpkg -S /usr/lib/nvidia-340/bin/nvidia-smi
nvidia-340: /usr/lib/nvidia-340/bin/nvidia-smi
```

Comment: It's super weird, but I can't find this alternative, even after reinstalling multiples times.  Maybe the nvidia driver install is silently aborting or failing halfway through?

Comment: Wow, I've just learned something new - `dpkg -S` would not find symlinks (in case of alternatives). @fmoo - well, check all files with `dpkg -L nvidia-390` (or whichever version you have), find `nvidia-smi` binary, and call it with absolute path, or add this location to your `$PATH` variable.