# Problem installing Ubuntu 15.10 on Asus K501UX (NVIDIA drivers)

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, package-management, 15.10, ubuntu-gnome

I'm trying to install Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 (but I've also tried with cassical Ubuntu getting the same results) on an Asus K501UX. Since it has a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M with Optimus Technology, when I boot from the usb I get a very long list of nouveau errors, but apart from that everything goes well (even if the icons and windows are very very small due to the high resolution of the screen). The fact is that, when the installation comes to "Restoring previously installed packages", I get a long list of errors like "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages" for (as far as I could see) *every* package (including important system packages, like xorg or similar), and at the end of the installation a message says that something went wrong and that I may have to reinstall some packages manually.

Then, if I reboot, I get the "Loading initial ramdisk", then the screen goes completely blank and nothing happens, the notebook just blocks (I tried Ctrl+Alt+F3 in order to do something from the command line, but nothing happens).

What can I do in order to at least make Ubuntu boot successfully once, so that I can install bumblebee nvidia drivers?

Comment: Please refer(http://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04)

Comment: Ok, actually I managed to solve the problem, adding "nouveau.modeset=0" to the boot options, then installed bumblebee...

Comment: @Leonardo I've created an answer based on the above comments. Please consider accepting it so other users can have a working solution. Or let me know if anything is missing and I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the boot parameters line in `/etc/default/grub` for example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"
```

Then update your grub config using:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Finally install `bumblebee` as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/452557/205638).

(This answer based on comments from @Ashu and @Leonardo.)