# How do I get Bumblebee & primus to work?

Tags: graphics, 16.10, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

I'm currently using a Lenovo Z40 running on NVIDIA GeForce GT820m GPU.  It's currently running on nvidia-378 drivers.

I used this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/452557/558318) to get it to work, but, unfortunately, it wouldn't.

[image]

Comment: What Nvidia drivers have you installed? And how?

Comment: @CelticWarrior currently using nvidia-378 and installed it via the graphics-drivers ppa

Comment: Before anything else make sure you have it enabled in BIOS/UEFI: https://support.lenovo.com/es/en/solutions/ht076090

Comment: read here & see if this works better - http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-install-and-configure-bumblebee.html

Comment: @doug I don't know what happened, but after I installed kernel 4.9.9, it worked...so far.