# After installing Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire 4830 laptop the CPU is overheating

Tags: cpu, acer, overheating

After I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop Acer Aspire 4830TG my computer is overheating too much and working very slow. I'm guessing is that something makes my computer's CPU overwork or there's some inconsistency with something on my computer. Could you please tell how can I fix this problem?

Comment: There are several power management utilities available - I use `tlp`, and another mentioned often is `thermald` - both of these are available in the Ubuntu repositories, have you tried either or both?

Comment: Well I've tried this program called Bumblebee, which was recommended in several sites, but it doesn't seem to work on mine, so I'm searching for other programs. I will try this tlp or thermald. How can I install it on ubuntu? Do you happen to know the command for it?

Comment: From the command line:  `sudo apt-get install tlp thermald` will install both of them.  After install, you should reboot.

Comment: Bumblebee is a graphics control utility, used be people with dual graphics cards (Nvidia I believe) to turn off an unused graphics processor.  Some information about Bumblebee can be found at [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

Comment: You might also review some of the Q&A about bumblebee - it *may* help with some of the heat issue, but apparently it can be complicated to setup and use.  [https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Install-and-usage](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Install-and-usage) and [https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04) would be a good starting place.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting TLP and Thermald. What about Bublebee, I think it's still useful for my computer coz my computer has a dual graphic card, I believe.

Comment: As I wrote above, it *may* help - I don't have a dual graphics card, and cannot competently comment on that issue, but you might start a new question about how to use it effectively...